# Get all form elements and irregular characters

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form that can have any number of elements.  Each element has a few characteristics.  How can i get all the form's data into a url for ajax posting?

the variable id is the id of the given item.

```
 Item 1
  <input type='text' name='<?php echo $id . "['name']";?>' id='i_<?php echo $id . "['name']";?>'>
  <input type='text'  name='<?php echo $id . "['size']";?>' id='i_<?php echo $id . "['size']";?>'>

 Item 2
  <input type='text' name='<?php echo $id . "['name']";?>' id='i_<?php echo $id . "['name']";?>'>
  <input type='text'  name='<?php echo $id . "['size']";?>' id='i_<?php echo $id . "['size']";?>'>

 Item 3
  <input type='text' name='<?php echo $id . "['name']";?>' id='i_<?php echo $id . "['name']";?>'>
  <input type='text'  name='<?php echo $id . "['size']";?>' id='i_<?php echo $id . "['size']";?>'>
```

if i do

```
 var inputs = $('#formName :input');
 var data = "";
 inputs.each(function() {
    data += this.name+"="+$(this).val()+"&";
});
```

the brackets in the identifier mess everything all up.  I know im am going about this incorrectly.  What should i be doing?

if i do serialize the same thing occurs.  I know its not ideal to use brackets in a element id, but how else can i associate a few characteristics of each item to the id?

Here is my rendered form:

```
 <form name='formName' id='formName' action='#'>
 <ul id="sortable">

<li class="ui-state-default" id='201817'>
        <input type='button' class='removeItem' value='remove'>
        <input type='text' name='201817['name']' id='a_201817['name']' value='hat'>
        <input type='text' name='201817['size']' id='a_201817['size']' value='small'>
</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id='501817'>
        <input type='button' class='removeItem' value='remove'>
        <input type='text' name='501817['name']' id='a_501817['name']' value='shirt'>
        <input type='text' name='501817['size']' id='a_501817['size']' value='small'>
</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id='522227'>
        <input type='button' class='removeItem' value='remove'>
        <input type='text' name='522227['name']' id='a_522227['name']' value='shirtB'>
        <input type='text' name='522227['size']' id='a_522227['size']' value='Large'>
</li>
 </ul>
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you show your rendered html form?

Comment: why not just remove the brackets and use `_` instead, then parse out the `_` on receiving end. Serialize form then loop over `$_POST` or `$_GET` to parse out names and ID's

Comment: so you want it to specifically say string"[name]" ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to put together a `GET` request. Use `jQuery.post()` instead and serialize your form into the `data` parameter.

Comment: or are you trying to get $id[name]?

Comment: You probably need to change the way you are working with the data yo are trying to post.  Try building your input names in the form `name[id]`, `size[id]` This will give you two nice arrays to work with in PHP `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['size']` each array would have id of item as key.

Comment: @charlietfl using _size  is ugly.  If I can not find another solution i will.

Comment: @peterchon  I am trying to have a number of items with size,name and other fields.  I dont care really how it gets passed, I just need to send it to the ajax processor with the characteristics associated to the item.

Comment: @MikeBrant this would be fine if I wasn't passing it through ajax, and just a second php page.

Comment: using ajax is irelevant to php end

Comment: if i knew all the elements and it wasnt a dynamic size  i could do var item = $('#555227\\['size'\\]).val();

Comment: @bart2puck What does passing it through AJAX have to do with the form formatting? You can serialize() the data with either approach. One just leaves you with a bunch of variable key names in `$_POST` that you need to guess at (or iterate through all `$_POST` keys to evaluate). The other gives you two arrays in `$_POST` with known key names (`name` and `size`).

Comment: @bart2puck You also should use `"` around your HTML property values.  Right now you have a problem with your property delimiter and the array key values both using `'` to delimit.

Comment: @MikeBrant maybe im not sure what you are saying.  either way i post the data, i am using an array as the element id/name and it will get all garbaged up during serialize...

Comment: @MikeBrant  you got it.  The single quotes is garbaging it all up.

Comment: @bart2puck Your inputs should look like `<input type="text" name="name[id]" value="?" />` and `<input type="text" name="size[id]" value="?" />` WHere `id` is the value you populate from PHP and `?` is whatever you need to populate for value (this is not clear from your example).  This will give you nice arrays to work with in `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['size']`

Comment: yea, you have it @mikebrant .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [form.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) it will consider all `:input` fields. Also remember that serialize will consider the element `name` and not the `id`.

So Try:

```
var data = $('#formName').serialize();
```

Comment: already tried this,  I end up with POST data like 522227%Bname&52227%B=size and just gets ugly.....

Comment: @bart2puck The ugliness you mention has NOTHING to do with `serialize()` and EVERYTHING to do with the way you are naming the inputs.  Please see comments below original post for suggestion on how to clean this up. The answer given here should be all you have to do in javascript side to get the data ready for POSTing.